# Outlook add-in disable automatic compression of JPEG attachment

Tags: c#, email, attachment, outlook-addin

I am writing an Outlook add-in to be able to insert automatically an image into an email using CID.
However, everytime I add an image as attachment (jpeg), the image is compressed automatically by Outlook and I have a big lost of quality.
Is it possible to avoid compression of images for attachment?

Here is the code that I am using so far:

```
var attachment = mailItem.Attachments.Add( @"D:\\image.jpg" , Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem , null , "Some image display name" );
string imageCid = "image.jpg@123";
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001F", "image/jpeg"); // PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", imageCid); // PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8514000B", true); // Hide attachment in the email
mailItem.HTMLBody = String.Format( "<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\" width='450' height='150' alt=''></body>" , imageCid);
```

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much you can do if the message is then displayed by Outlook. You can try to add the image immediately prior to it being sent (`Aplication.ItemSend` event).

Comment: So far, I am adding the image when the email explorer window is opened.For example, when an user clicks on "New","Reply" ...

What you mean is that instead to do that, I should add the image before to send the email instead. In that case, the images is not compressed?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, from my experience the images are only modified when they are in an inspector.

Comment: Thanks I make it working. I have tested and when an image is added through the send event, there are no compression.Thanks again